# imagettftext doesn't output anything

Tags: php

I'm using the basic example from php.net on my local machine (Macbook Pro w/ Snow Leopard) to display a line of text using the GD library, but nothing is showing for me. I have display errors turned on and I double checked that the GD library and the FreeType library is being used, but I continue to get blank white pages. Here's the code I'm testing, taken directly from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

I supsect it's the 'arial.ttf' part that's causing problems. Any way for me to test that? I figured a default install would surely have that available.

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Here's my PHP info for GD:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.4
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 8
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.5.2
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

Comment: do you have the file "arial.ttf" available for access by the PHP script?

Comment: Shouldn't that be available by default or do I have to provide the absolute path to that font? If so, do I just download the font from somewhere and point to it?

Comment: So it looks like I do need to provide the full path to the font. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font file "arial.ttf" is not provided with PHP by default.

Your script requires access to the font file in order to use it.